# mysql 2 queries to one

Tags: mysql, merge

i have two mysql queries the first one is

```
SELECT  `first_name` ,  `last_name` ,  `email` ,  `mobile`
FROM  `member_master` 
WHERE  `id` = $member_id  AND  `dob` =  $date
```

and second one is

```
SELECT  `email` 
FROM  `member_master`
WHERE  `id` = $member_id  AND  `dob` !=  $date
```

need to merge this 2 queries in one single query how is that possible ?

Comment: with mysql_query you can't actually execute 2 queries at once

Answer (score 1):

if you really want two separate results with one callout, I suppose you could issue a UNION with flag (result_id) and nulls where the second result has no columns:

```
select * from
(
SELECT 1 as result_id
 , first_name 
 , last_name
 , email
 , mobile
FROM member_master
WHERE id = $member_id AND dob = $date

union 

SELECT 2 as result_id
 , null
 , null
 , email
 , null
FROM member_master
WHERE id = $member_id AND dob != $date
) my_result
order by result_id
```

that way you can identify the appropriate set.

**EDIT**: added the outer select so that we can order by our "flag" column, so we can deal with one set at a time. But you will stil have two sets within one result, which have to parsed.

Comment: how to fetch using mysql_fetch_array ? both the result in different variables.

Comment: if you read the two sqls again, you will find out ... is a select all after all

Answer (score 0):

Well being the same table you can use an OR statement like this (the only problem is that all records will contain  `first_name` ,  `last_name` etc ):

```
 SELECT  `first_name` ,  `last_name` ,  `email` ,  `mobile`
                   FROM  `member_master` WHERE  (`id` = $member_id  AND  `dob` =  $date ) or ( `id` = $member_id  AND  `dob` !=  $date)
```

Comment: thanks..but i need both the queries. i need the information of the person whose dob = $date and even of those who are != $date. but in a way where i can send emails to who are != $date in a single while loop. so basicaly i want to loop both information array in single while loop.